# Startup failed in gradle when i update my old project to new

Tags: android

unexpected token:

> com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0 @ line 27, column 20.
>
> Implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'

1 error

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "stking.age"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        Implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
        Implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the answers provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all set **`buildToolVersion`** like `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"`
- change `Implementation` to `implementation`

Your full gradle file will look like.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "stking.age"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add `buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'`

it should look like this  `buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'`

and make your `Implementation` to `implementation`